# Converting text field to date in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to convert a text field from a SAS table with the form '2014-12-31' into a another SAS table as a date field.  The below does not work:

```
proc sql outobs=50;
create table Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf as
  select FACS_Schema_ID '',
        'DBACCT*'n as ACCOUNT_NUM '',
        DBLSTDTI as Date_Listed format=date09.
  from sqlsrv10.Acct_Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf;
quit;
```

I get the following error:
ERROR: Character expression requires a character format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `INPUT` to convert types in SAS.

```
proc sql outobs=50;
create table Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf as
  select FACS_Schema_ID '',
        'DBACCT*'n as ACCOUNT_NUM '',
        input(DBLSTDTI,yymmdd10.) as Date_Listed format=date09.
  from sqlsrv10.Acct_Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf;
quit;
```

That is most likely the correct informat based on your question.